# TabbedForm - displaying toolbar (submit button) conditionally on FormTab

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

is there a way to remove submit button (toolbar) conditionally in specific Tabs, when using TabbedForm? (react-admin)

[image: TabbedForm]

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I did it using a custom toolbar:

```js
<TabbedForm toolbar={<PostEditToolbar {...props} />}>...
```

The toolbar looks like this:

```js
const PostEditToolbar = props => {
  const { hasList, hasEdit, hasShow, hasCreate, redirect, ...rest } = props
  return (
    <Toolbar {...props}>
      <Route exact path={'/Posts/:id/:tab_index'} render={props => ''} />
      <Route
        exact
        path={'/Posts/:id'}
        render={props => (
          <SaveButton redirect={`/Posts/${rest.id}`} {...rest} />
        )}
      />
    </Toolbar>
  )
}
```

You will need to `import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'` for this and also adjust the route paths as needed.

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's not possible unless you create your very own `TabbedForm`component

Comment: perhaps some hackish way? i've tried with some css magic but can't seem to find a good solution...

Comment: No, I'm quite sure you'll have to make a custom `TabbedForm`

Answer (score 0):

You may use onClick on tab and manage state based on that, example below

```
const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState("Comments");

const handleTabClick = (tabLabel) => {
  setCurrentTab(tabLabel);
};

const toolbar = (
  <div>
    {(currentTab != "Comments") ? (
        <SaveButton />
    ) : null }
  </div>
);

<TabbedForm.Tab
  label="Comments"
  onClick={() => handleTabClick("Comments")}
></TabbedForm.Tab>
```